# Data layer Abstraction from Business layer for search

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, abstraction, search, elasticsearch

This is regarding designing a search api. We have 3 tier architecture now using Spring MVC. All communications are via REST api.

```
UI <-> Business <-> Data(sql).
```

Now to implement faster search, we are planning to index data from sql. So any write to data-layer, will be indexed in es as well.

```
BL (writes)-> DL(writes)->ElasticSearch
```

Now for any search calls, I am planning to make BL call ES directly.

`Search-> BL -> ElasticSearch`(much faster compared to sql search)

ES will be tightly coupled with BL here.But are we really abstracting the Data Access here if we directly call ES from BL.

Should we be calling `Search-> BL-> DL-> ES` ? In this case, we will be losing most of the advantages of ES as we need to make one more n/w call.

Which one is the ideal approach?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would advocate performance that benefits client over the choice of developer ease (after all client is the one who is paying).

If you really have these two options then go with 
Search-> BL -> ElasticSearch(much faster compared to sql search)

**Suggestion:**

1. Implement an interface between Bl and ES. this interface will give you some abstraction.
2. Implement the interface in ES. where you will implement methods like search(params).
3. Use abstract class instead of interface if necessary. depends on your usecase. (eg. Consider multiple inheritence problem of abstract classes vs interface etc)

**Benefit:**

1. If at later point you decide to change ES to someother search mechanism, you can just implement the same interface again and you are good to go.
2. Maintenance is easier as it provides some level of loose coupling.

Please feel free to comment if you have more questions.

hope that helps